# Как разбить список на элементы?

Tags: python, парсер, list

Пишу парсер лога сервера. В цикле из файла инфа читается в список. Например:

```
print templink[1]
```

выдает такое:

> ['/ulanude/profile/5207815350129083?hash=Ag89ky880B4IJ1HB7bcfuvly18361J34d8B5237A042C8717f68868G81J0I7A478','/ulanude/profile/5207815350129083', '/ulanude/profil/5207815350296005?hash=Ad8eky88036IJ1HB77cBuvly18361J34d6B7237A05998717fe8168G82J0I7A474']

Т.е. в одном индексе списка как бы много значений(в данном случае 2).

А надо чтоб было просто:

> ['/ulanude/profile/5207815350129083?hash=Ag89ky880B4IJ1HB7bcfuvly18361J34d8B5237A042C8717f68868G81J0I7A478']

Фишка в том что таких записей будет очень много. И в одном индексе может быть до 30 значений.
Как мне разбить список, на элементы и записать их в другой по одному?

Comment: Подходит ли простой вариант:
>>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [[i, ] for i in d]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Вам нужны листы, чтобы в каждлом по одному значению было? Чем тогда такие листы отличаются просто от элементов? В Matlab например так и есть: каждое значение - матрица 1на1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут товарищ вингер дал решение задачки,
где используется генератор списков.

другое дело, может задуматься о более правильном считывании, что-бы такой байды не плодить.

В смысле , каждому элементу списка присвоить ОДНО значение, а тут- сразу несколько, зачем усложнять.

Comment: Я решил проблему сделав вложенный цикл в котором поочередно все элементы из одно списка, кладутся (append) во второй.

Comment: а разве вначале было не такое состояние?

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант:

```
>> d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>> d

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>> [[i, ] for i in d]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```